# my RasPi 4B 4GB will not display on my tv

Tags: hdmi, pi-4

I just got my raspberry pi 4 4gb in the mail today. I plugged it up to my TCL Roku TV via hdmi but nothing would display on the screen.

Comment: is the micro-HDMI to HDMI cable decent quality? which HDMI on the pi did you use? And the most important question of all - what operating system have you installed?

Comment: Does the RasPi is running with a red light and a flashing green light?